# Button is not moving when I change its coordinates

Tags: html, css

Given this code :

```
<style type="text/css">
#button{
width: 5em;  height: 2em;
background-color:#62B1F6;
font-size:20px;
position:static;
left: 400px;
top:485px;
z-index: 1;}
</style>
```

When I change the parameters of `left,top` , the button doesn't move .

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: @Arif: Thanks , but that's not the reason .

Answer (score 1):

You can't move a static object with top/bottom/left/right attributes!

It should be relative/absolute/fixed in order to apply the top/bottom/left/right attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Try `position: relative`:

```
#button {
    width: 5em; height: 2em;
    background-color: #62B1F6;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;
    left: 400px;
    top: 485px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```